# How can I ordering my mysql query to double criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with SQL query.
In one table I have columns with names id and subid. Some of the product connects to other via subid in the same table.
Example:

```
ID   | Name     |   Status    |   Subid | Location
---------------------------------------------------------
1    | Milk     |   SA        |         |  Box 1
2    | MyDay    |   SA        |   1     |
3    | Kitkat   |   SA        |   4     |
4    | Chocolate|   SA        |         |  Box 2
5    | Twix     |   SA        |   4     | 
6    | Bounty   |   SA        |   4     |
7    | Milkbox  |   SA        |   1     |
```

with another many results in table.

I want to make query
SELECT * FROM products WHERE status='SA' ORDER BY Location ASC, ...

I want my sort to seems like this:

```
ID   | Name     |   Status    |   Subid | Location
---------------------------------------------------------
4    | Chocolate|   SA        |         |  Box 2 // If it's parent result
3    | Kitkat   |   SA        |   4     |        // It's a child for Choco
5    | Twix     |   SA        |   4     |        // It's a child for Choco 
6    | Bounty   |   SA        |   4     |        // It's a child for Choco
1    | Milk     |   SA        |         |  Box 1 // If it's parent result
2    | MyDay    |   SA        |   1     |        // It's a child for Milk
7    | Milkbox  |   SA        |   1     |        // It's a child for Milk
```

After every parent result to shows his children connected via subid to id

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "order by all products"? None of the examples you've posted show data sorted by `Name`.

Comment: If I understood your desired result your question is a bit incomplete. What you should ask for is: "How can I order the products by its location first and then its subproducts"

Comment: show the desired result, would help us understanding your OP.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu it is there... its just not clear enough that the second result is the desired one :)

Comment: @maSTAShuFu: The OP already did. Look at the final table in the question.

Comment: Please show all your tables

Comment: @JorgeCampos, yes I want to order it like in the second example

Comment: How deep can that id/subid relations go? Just one level? And what's your version of MySQL?

Comment: ordering is affected by data type, is `subid` an integer column or is it varchar?

Comment: @stickybit yes just one level. MySQL version 5.5.47-MariaDB

Comment: @Used_By_Already - It's Varchar

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
order by coalesce(subid, id),
         (case when subid is null then 1 else 2 end);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=046eb4775131b765dec4db8c78930b5d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: No. I want after every main id to sort every subid after it. On this type of query first sort all products with empty subids and after that sorts other subids where are not empty.

Comment: @RossenVassilev . . . I don't follow.  This is returning *exactly* the order you specify in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can (self) join the parent product and order by its location or by the location of the child product (if no parent was found) and the `subid` not being `NULL` to get the parent products to the top for each location.

```
SELECT t1.*
       FROM elbat t1
            LEFT JOIN elbat t2
                      ON t2.id = t1.subid
       WHERE t1.status = 'SA'
       ORDER BY coalesce(t2.location,
                         t1.location),
                t1.subid IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: I have only one table. The both of columns are in one table.

Comment: @RossenVassilev: And my query only uses one table... ;)

Comment: Please see my edited question post. Can you understand me now? After every parent result to shows his child results. Now with this query shows me first all children for each parent and after that shows all parents. On WHERE clause I have an error in mysql syntaxis : "#1052 - Column 'status' in where clause is ambiguous"

Comment: @RossenVassilev: Yes, right, I missed to qualify `status`. I fixed that.